# Running an executable file from SAS BASE and Enterprise Guide - any differences?

Tags: sas, executable, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I've got a executable file (without source files, only .exe file) which I am trying to run in a .sas file, using a file reference to an unnamed pipe:

```
%macro process_file(path);
    %let filepath = %trim(&path.);
    %let filename = %scan(&path., -1, %str(\));

    filename flf pipe "&progpath. ""&filepath."" ""&workpath.\&filename..log""";

    data hnd_tmp;
        length line $1024.;
        infile flf; input;
        line = left(trim(compbl(_infile_)));    
    run;
%mend process_file;
```

This script basically returns a list of processes which are blocking a particular file (filepath) and returns output to the log file (the third argument).

When I run my code in SAS 9.3 it works well and I receive a desired output, but when I use SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1, the script throws an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Could not list processes locking resource. Failed to get size of result.
    at ProcessHelpers.FileUtil.WhoIsLocking(String path)
    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.start(String[] args)
    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args
```

I cannot debug the application, so this exception tells me almost nothing.

I am wondering if there are any differences between running programs in SAS BASE and SAS Enterprise Guide in terms of e.g. environmental variables, system options etc. - something that could possibly lead to the program throwing an exception.

I have been looking for a solution in SAS documentation and papers but with no luck so far.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edited to provide more details, see comments.**

The solution has been tested directly on a networked server and the program throws an exception. I can replicate this situation on a RACE Virtual Machine locally and locally on a server as well. All the servers are running on Windows. Hardcoding the commands did not help, still there's an issue. XCMD is turned on. It seems to be a problem with invoking the code not locally.

Comment: System variables, path, etc are probably different through EG.  Can you execute X commands to echo those values and see if something is different from when you log in directly?

Comment: @DomPazz: I am not exactly sure what do you mean by "X commands", I've run a code do get all macro variables both from BASE and EG and I am trying to examine them and find differences. Available [here @ pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4FZPa8AS).

Comment: `X <command>;` runs an OS command from SAS.  It works like the PIPE Filename you are using.  You could run some OS echos to see what is different between the environments.  If that is the problem, then you can get your admin to help you fix it.

Comment: When you run it in EG, are you still connecting to 'local SAS server' or are you connecting to a (networked) SAS server?

Comment: @Joe: I am quite sure that I am connected to the networked SAS server. In fact, I am developing this solution on a virtual machine with SAS (so local server is involved, but it has also been tested on a networked SAS server - a cluster of two servers, precisely saying.

Comment: @gczarnocki The reason for the question is that I'm asking whether when you run it in Base SAS vs. EG, are you running on the same SAS installation or not.  Base SAS always is running on 'local server' (local to wherever Base SAS is running) while EG can either run locally or networked.  I don't think there's likely to be a difference between Base SAS and EG in terms of running the application, unless the application isn't written to run in unattended mode perhaps, but there could easily be a difference between your local machine and the SAS Server.

Comment: @Joe: I cannot edit my comment now, so, once again: The solution has been tested directly on a networked server and throws an exception and I can replicate this situation on my RACE Virtual Machine. Every time, when I run the code, I am connected to the server which EG is connecting to (the same machine), so I think I run my programs 'locally on a networked server', correct me if I'm wrong. Although, the connection profile in EG is set to 'remote', it's just the name of the machine I am working on.

Comment: @gczarnocki As long as the sas.exe that is running the code is the same, then you're fine there - that's what I'm getting at.  EG doesn't run anything - it submits code to sas.exe somewhere (or the unix/linux/mainframe equivalent of sas.exe).  If the same sas.exe works with running directly but fails when EG submits code to it, then EG seems to be the issue.

Comment: When you run in base SAS (directly through sas.exe), are you running it in interactive mode, or in batch mode?  If you're only running interactive, perhaps try running a test in batch mode, just to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Also, try taking the macro code out of the equation.  Hardcode the commands that the macro is generating and check to see if it runs on both.  In other words, come up with the simplest possible command that you can to make it fail, so that you can rule out everything else.

Comment: What's the status of the XCMD option in EG and Base? Maybe this is naive, but isn't pipe and XCMD turned off by default in EG so that you need to explicitly turn in on to allow you to run an exe from EG?

Comment: Is you EG session connecting to a Linux SAS server?  If so the \  the macro adds to the path for in &filename could be a problem (Linux wants /).  Agree with @Robert, hardcode the command so you can see everything you are passing.  Also, maybe try passing the executable a few different paths.

Comment: @Joe: It has been tested both in interactive mode and batch mode - no luck. Running the exact command in a CLI on behalf of the user logged into EG seems to be okay, to be honest. XCMD is turned on in the configuration of the workspace server and invoking the command fails in Enterprise Guide.

Comment: @RobertPenridge: I deleted the macro code and left a filename pipe statement and data step only. Still, Enterprise Guide fails to execute code properly (exception thrown) and SAS BASE succeeds. So it must be some kind of a difference between invoking this code in SAS BASE and Enterprise Guide, maybe concerning the permissions, or user who on behalf of this code is executing.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is successful in Base SAS (on the target machine), and unsuccessful in an EG session connected to run on that same Server, then I'd suspect an issue with user permissions.

It is possible to launch an interactive Base SAS session with the same configuration as an EG (remote client) session, using a shell command - eg as follows:

```
"C:\SAS\Config\Lev1\SASApp\WorkspaceServer\WorkspaceServer.bat" -terminal -splash
```

Try logging onto the RACE image as the same user you are connecting with in EG (sasdemo?) and run your code in the BASE SAS session launched from the command above.

- If this is unsuccessful (error message), the issue is server side, and most likely username permissions.
- If your filename pipe works above, then I'd make double sure you are actually connecting to that same workspace server in your EG session (check your connection profile).

To summarise, yes there ARE differences, mainly in the `.cfg` file, but may also be found in the various `_usermods` files used in creating the final SAS launch command.  Just follow the contents of the .bat file above to see them.